# Refund vs Cancel on the google play merchant account

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I have a paid app and I have LVL licensing implemented. Sometimes I get request to cancel order and refund.

If I go to my merchant account and click on refund, then the money is refunded. However, a new button called "Cancel" appears. What is this for? Shouldnt a refund a cancel the order. I usually click cancel as well.

Basically I want to refund the order and ensure that LVL does not let the user continue with using the app after the refund has been issued.

Thanks

Comment: No one knows this?